# Cognos parse xml - cognos side or sql side?

Tags: sql, xml, cognos

I have a view that pulls 3 columns from an audit table:

```
Col1        Col2     Col3
(String)    (Long)   (String)
```

Inside the long the long(Col2) I have XML:

```
<AuditDetail AuditType="TrackableItem">
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute DataType="class java.lang.Long" Name="Lockid"
            NewValue="11" OldValue="12"/>
        <Attribute DataType="class java.lang.String" Name="OverrideCode"
            NewValue="8899" OldValue="9998"/>
    </Attributes>
</AuditDetail>
```

I need my cognos side to display 4 columns `(Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4)`, two columns will be columns that the view already returns, the other two need to be values selected from the xml `(AuditDetail/Attributes/Attribute/newvalue)`

How would I select the two data items from these xml files? would I parse somehow on the cognos side, or is there anyway to get the data values in the view?

Using oracle db.

Comment: Is the data stored as XML, or a string?

Comment: It is stored as a Long datatype

Answer (score 2):

Since it's stored as a string, it really isn't going to make much difference. You're going to use the same kind of string functions (instr, substr, etc) in Cognos or the view. And it will be a huge pain. Doing it in a view would only force you to do it once, at least. Here's an example to help you get started:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a01c5/35)

```
select
substr (col1
       ,(instr(col1,'NewValue="')+10)  -- This gets you to the end of the NewValue=" string
      ,(instr(col1,'NewValue="')+10) -  
          instr(col1,'=',(instr(col1,'NewValue="'))) --This gets you the length, the second value is the first occurence of '"' AFTER your start position
        )
from
AuditData
```

Comment: Hey Andrew,thanks for the reply and it would definitely work if was String, but i was mistaken and the data i am trying to parse through is Long. any other tips for Longs?

Comment: I'm confused.  That XML data has to be character.  Are the values you're trying to pull out Long?  If so, just cast them.